# Implementing data encryption in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to implement data encryption in my app locally, as well as transfer data over the network, after encrypting it.

Can anyone help me by guiding me to good documentation or resources to acheive this? I have looked upon Apple's cryptoClient application  but it's too cryptic(contains Bonjour sharing etc. which I don't need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to encrypt the files (check the documentation, there is a way to zip the data with a password) and since you are gonna transfer the data over the network you should make it as small as possible by zipping it.

This is a great tutorial on using ZipArchive:
http://icodeblog.com/2010/04/12/creating-a-document-centric-iphoneipad-application-with-own-file-format-using-ziparchive/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [SQLCipher](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/) to encrypt sqlite database, which can store your data locally and to transfer over internet you can simply use HTTPS.